# Custom Google Maps Overlay like Disney Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am interested in creating a google map like this https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/maps/ but I am having trouble finding information on how to go about it. I've looked on the googlemaps api but I can only see how to change the tiles on one zoom level and the colors. Can anyone point me in the right direction to create something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiles are served from a GIS tile server. Google Maps requests tiles using three parameters: X, Y, and Z (can be thought of as Lat, Long, and Zoom). The server gives entirely different tiles based on the zoom level (more detailed location items and labels). Google Maps doesn't do much work at all in this instance, it is all handled by the server and Google Maps renders what it is given.

Comment: So basically all I would need to do is tell google maps where the new tiles are on the server correct?

Comment: Take a look at image map type overlays. Read the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes and example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

Comment: You can create your own tile images using software such as GDAL2tiles: http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html